# clarification of image properties in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, cgrect, cgcontextref

I'm trying to create randomly generated images for a class I'm writing in objective-c, and was just hoping to get a little clarification as to different image properties and types.
   I want to create the following function:

-(UIImage*)randomlyGenerateAnImage;

This function will use member data to create a quasi-random algorithmically generated UIImage.

I'm really having trouble understanding the relation between UIImages, CGRects, and CGContextRefs.  Which is the one I draw on and what do I assign to the UIImage.

*Edit*
  I'm trying to generate my image on the fly, something like:

UIImage * newImage = [[UIImage alloc] "initBlankImageWithSize(X, Y)"];

CGContextRef * newContext = "getContextFromImage(newImage)";

"draw on newContext......";

return newImage;

Comment: Not what you asked, but for 'creative coding' type practice you might find  openFrameworks (http://www.openframeworks.cc/) easier to manage since a lot of the graphic pipeline plumbing is simplified

Answer (score 0):

For a `UIViewController` that is filled up by a `UIImageView` you would do

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[sigBox.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
//drawing code that says CGContext a lot
sigBox.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

To draw on the `UIImage` "owned" by the `UIImageView`. So you draw on the `CGContext` that is defined by a `CGRect`, and then you can return a `UIImage` from the `CGContext`. I doubt that explanation made anything clearer, but hopefully the code did.

Answer (score 0):

You need a context where you can draw in. You can get the current context with `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`.

You can create an image from the current context via `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`

The `CGRect` is a rectangle inside your view.

You should read Apple's drawing guide to get more informations.